# I get double quotes within JSON values when using request on URL. Handle without regex?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm parsing a web page

```
def getDailyTVnuList(channel = 'kanal-9', datestr = '2021-02-12'):
    r = requests.get('https://www.tv.nu/kanal/{}/{}'.format(channel, datestr))
    m = re.search(r'<script>__INITIAL_STATE__ = "(.+?)"<\/script>', r.text)
    # tmpText = re.sub(r'( ")([\w ]+?)(" )',r' \2 ', m.group(1).replace('\\',''))
    return json.loads(m.group(1).replace('\\',''))['schedule']['broadcasts']
```

In words, a webpage containing tv-listings. I seem to find the json of interest within the script __INITIAL_STATE, which is why I do the first regex search.
On that specific date in the example (2021-02-12) there are double quotes inside a value, which causes

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 20989 (char 20988)
  File "C:\Users\tohek\Dropbox\TV-Guide\DplusScraper.py", line 14, in getDailyTVnuList
    return json.loads(m.group(1).replace('\\',''))['schedule']['broadcasts']
  File "C:\Users\tohek\Dropbox\TV-Guide\DplusScraper.py", line 44, in <module>
    channelList = getDailyTVnuList()
```

The double quotes are here (swedish, but that's not the point :) ):

```
m.group(1).replace('\\','')[20950:21105]
'"description":"Otto vill ge bort sin "wacky yak" till en kompis men gåvan vill inte bli bortgiven. Det blir kor på isen när Atz agerar kofösare åt en vän."'
```

Now, if I insert the tmpText (commented in first code snippet) in json.loads(), I can get rid of the double quotes in description without removing them from all key/values, and my code "works". But there must be a more robust way to handle this. Right? (also, I'm kind of curious why all the '\' has to be removed, is it poorly formatted on the web page or is it, more probably, my fault?)

UPDATE 2021-02-10, I THINK I SOLVED IT:
I fiddled around with some trial and error... to perform json.dumps() on

```
string = '{\"schedule\":{\"id\":67,\"name\":\"Kanal...}'
```

did not work. I tried making a dictionary of it, with one key for which "string" was the value. That did not work. After that, I tried to create a valid json-string of it by inserting a valid key in the beginning (and closing bracket in the end). And by using two consecutive dumps on it, it worked! Like this:

```
def getDailyTVnuList(channel = 'kanal-9', datestr = '2021-02-12'):
    r = requests.get('https://www.tv.nu/kanal/{}/{}'.format(channel, datestr))
    m = re.search(r'<script>__INITIAL_STATE__ = "(.+?)"<\/script>', r.text)

    tmpJson = '{"data":"' + m.group(1) + '"}'
    tmpDict1 = json.loads(tmpJson)
    tmpDict2 = json.loads(tmpDict1['data'])
    return tmpDict2['schedule']['broadcasts']
```

This way, data is formatted (and escaped) correctly all the way down. I can't really see how this trick worked, I'm reading up on json but don't understand it yet. Why the first dumps was not enough is yet beyond my understanding.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `).replace('\\','')` part? You seem to be removing the backslashes that are needed to properly escape the quotes.

Comment: I get another error:
`Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
  File "C:\Users\tohek\Dropbox\TV-Guide\DplusScraper.py", line 14, in getDailyTVnuList
    return json.loads(m.group(1))['schedule']['broadcasts']
  File "C:\Users\tohek\Dropbox\TV-Guide\DplusScraper.py", line 44, in <module>
    channelList = getDailyTVnuList()`

and the m.group(1) looks like this:
`'{\\"schedule\\":{\\"id\\":67,\\"name\\":\\"Kanal 9\\"....' etc`

Comment: Oh, so the webpage delivers all quotes as escaped quotes, even those that must not be escaped. Bummer.

Comment: I dumped r.text to a file to double check. `<script>__INITIAL_STATE__ = "{\"schedule\":{\"id\":67,\"name\":\"Kanal... and so on"</script>`. In there, the double quotes are actually escaped and the backslashes are also escaped as `\"description\":\"Otto vill ge bort sin \\\"wacky yak\\\" till...\" `. I need to unpack this somehow before I process with json.loads?